# How to interpret different shapes of a log-log graph?

Tags: regression, logarithm

I have a number vs size plot for two species. I'm trying to figure out through some basic plotting what shapes it could take-up. I suspected some sort of hump shaped curve where size peaks at intermediate numbers. I plotted a quadratic function for the raw data (left side). However, because the points were too spread out I plotted them on a log-log scale. A log-log scale with a linear function y ~ x(middle graph) shows that species B has no size dependencies. And a log-log scale with a quadratic function y~x + x2 (right) shows that Species B could be peaking at intermediate densities. I'm wondering the best way to interpret these graphs just on the basis of the log-log graphs. I will eventually get to model fitting and comparison but I want to understand what these different shapes on the the log-log graphs mean.  [image]